# iPhone App communication using phone numbers?

Tags: iphone, networking, localization, communication

Is it somehow possible to use phone number of receiver to send app messages?

The idea is the user don't have to know anything about ips, etc. just a phone number. Then the app can find this user and send messages (app protocol).

Sorry complete newbie question, but was just wondering if there's a connection… I didn't find any information with search engine…

Comment: Most carriers have the format, ##########@carrier.com, eg. 5555555555@verizon.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could do this, but it would require both parties to have your app installed and you would likely need to create some sort of intermediate web-based service to store their account information (username, password, phone number, UDID, etc) then use that service to send the app messages from the sender to the receiver.

Assuming both of these users would be using an iPhone it will probably just be easier to wait until [iMessage](http://www.apple.com/ios/ios5/features.html#imessage) is released with iOS 5 in a month or two since it will work similar to FaceTime in that you can use phone numbers, emails, etc and works between all iOS devices running iOS 5.